# Notify in a specific "logchannel" if someone joins a specific voice channel

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Pls help me out
i tried much but it wont work

```
@bot.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    notifchannel = 702241043810353332
    channel = before.channel or after.channel
    if channel.id == 677216062013440030:
        if before.channel is None and after.channel is not None:
            await notifchannel.send("...")
```

Comment: Can you explain your question clearly?

Comment: "Won't work" it's too vague for us to be able to help you, please add any errors you're getting, what's your current result and what's the expected result, take a look at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to get the channel object via

```
notifchannel = member.guild.get_channel(702241043810353332)
```

instead of calling the function `send()` on the channel-id.

Comment: Or simply: `await bot.get_channel(ChannelID)`